# MVC 3: JSON get request is not fully deserialized

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to send a GET request, with JSON string in parameters.
Looks something like this:

```
var params = { "Url": "http://www.asdf.com", "Users": [{ "Name": "Bob" }, { "Name": "Bill"}] };
```

Sending via jQuery's get, query string on a server side is this:

> Url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.asdf.com&Users%5b0%5d%5bName%5d=Bob&Users%5b1%5d%5bName%5d=Bill

The problem is, the model gets the URL property populated, and it sees 2 items in users array, however, the user names stay null.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Edit:

This is the model:

```
public class Parameters
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public User[] Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your User model definition?

Comment: Just did. Looks like any properties that are of complex type are not deserialized.

Comment: You probably missing `JSON.Stringify()` as suggested in @Shyju's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can **POST** JSON data to your Action method and it will work  fine. MVC3 will do the model binding for JSON input.

Make sure you provide the **contentType** property value when making the ajax call.

```
var params = JSON.stringify(  { "Url": "http://www.asdf.com", 
                                "Users": [{ "Name": "Bob" }, 
                                          { "Name": "Bill"}] });
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AcceptJson","Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',   
    data: params, 
    success: function (r) {

    }
});
```

Assuming you have an action method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AcceptJson(Parameters model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        //check properties of model
    }        
    return Content("ha ha! Json works! Do something useful");
}
```

Your model binding will work fine.
[image]

Comment: POST will work, but I need a GET here... I kind of figured a way around this - I can url-encode JSON string and pass it as  a query string, deserializing it on a server, but if I can make it auto-wire - that'd be nicer.